# How to set expire time of Cookie using `ngx-cookie-service`

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, ngx-cookie-service

I am using `ngx-cookie-service` for my angular app. In the [official docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) it says I can add a third parameter for the expiration time like -

```
this.cookieService.set('CookieName', 'Cookie Value', 5);
```

The third parameter is for expire time in days. Is there any way to set the expiration time of the cookie in minutes or in an hour? IE: 30 mint or Hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the code here: https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/blob/master/projects/ngx-cookie-service/src/lib/cookie.service.ts#L105

You will see that expires is:

> Number of days until the cookies expires or an actual `Date`

As such, you just need to get the current date/time and add an hour to it like so:

```
const myDate: Date = new Date();
myDate.setHours( myDate.getHours() + 1 );
```

And then:

```
this.cookieService.set('CookieName', 'Cookie Value', myDate);
```

OR

```
this.cookieService.set('CookieName', 'Cookie Value', { expires: myDate });
```

Note, manipulating dates is much easier with a date manipulation library like `date-fns` which always returns a JS Date.

```
import { addHours } from 'date-fns';
const myDate: Date = addHours(new Date(), 1);
```

Obviously you will need to ... npm install date-fns ... for this to work. For alternative date manipulation libraries search for alternatives to `date-fns` with [npm trends](https://www.npmtrends.com/date-fns). Although, in my humble opinion, I consider `date-fns` to be top notch.

Docs for date-fns are [here](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/Getting-Started)